# How to fetch data in Spring Boot from table of Angular7

Tags: spring-boot, angular7

I created data table in angular and taking order input from customer. Customer will enter order data and click on submit. What I want that when customer will click on submit button that time this order data will be send to the my spring boot application and print.
How can I fetch this data in spring boot and display using get and post method? I am new to Angular and Spring Boot.

Comment: Use angular http services to send data as json to one of the spring boot application endpoints. It would be appreciated if you have some attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a reference from below link how to create API in spring boot and how to call it from angular.
  https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

Comment: Not usefull . I want to write POST method in angular for send the item code ,name and quantity enter by customer .and fetch this data from angular using GET method in angular . and print this data in spring boot

Comment: i created one arraylist and stored order data into list and passed this arraylist with POST method in service.and in Spring boot i write GET method to fetch this arraylist and print , but data is not print .

Comment: See in that link how I will send a object from angular service using post method and how I will get that same object in spring boot controller using post method not get method.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a array list data from angular to spring boot using post method then in spring boot you can receive same array list using **post** method not **get** method..